# IO - Objective-c GPUImage Lookup Filter make effect with lookup image 4x4

Tags: objective-c, macos, io, opengl-es, gpuimage

I know have a many solve make effect for image. But i choice GPUImage (`GPUImageLookupFilter`) make my image.

My source code i use.

```
GPUImagePicture *sourceImagePic = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:sourceImage];
GPUImagePicture *lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lookup.png"]];
GPUImageLookupFilter *lookupImageFilter = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];

[sourceImagePic addTarget:lookupImageFilter];
[lookupImageSource addTarget:lookupImageFilter];
[lookupImageFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];

[sourceImagePic processImage];
[lookupImageSource processImage];
resultImage = [lookupImageFilter imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

return resultImage;
```

First i use lookup image 8x8 (512<sup>2</sup>)

[image]

But when i working with array image (thumb in video or choice many image in library) memory higher.

I think if i use small lookup image (4x4) memory can reduced. I make a lookup image 4x4(16<sup>2</sup>).

[image]

And i try edit code of `GPUImageLookupFilter` but it not work.

```
 void main(){
 highp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

 highp float blueColor = textureColor.b * 63.0;

 highp vec2 quad1;
 quad1.y = floor(floor(blueColor) / 8.0);
 quad1.x = floor(blueColor) - (quad1.y * 8.0);

 highp vec2 quad2;
 quad2.y = floor(ceil(blueColor) / 8.0);
 quad2.x = ceil(blueColor) - (quad2.y * 8.0);

 highp vec2 texPos1;
 texPos1.x = (quad1.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);
 texPos1.y = (quad1.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);

 highp vec2 texPos2;
 texPos2.x = (quad2.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);
 texPos2.y = (quad2.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);

 lowp vec4 newColor1 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos1);
 lowp vec4 newColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos2);

 lowp vec4 newColor = mix(newColor1, newColor2, fract(blueColor));
 gl_FragColor = mix(textureColor, vec4(newColor.rgb, textureColor.w), intensity);
}
```

You can help me edit this code work with image 4x4.

Thank you!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following algorithm will work for any size of the lookup texture. You just have to adapt `tiles` to the number of the tiles in the x and y direction, and `colTexSize` to the full size of the color lookup texture.
The algorithm is identical to the original algorithm, except the constant size values, which have been replaced by the variables `tiles` and `colTexSize`.

```
void main()
{
    vec2 tiles      = vec2( 4.0, 4.0 );   // original texture vec2( 8.0, 8.0 )
    vec2 colTexSize = vec2( 64.0, 64.0 )  // original texture vec2( 512.0, 512.0 )

    highp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

    highp float blueColor = textureColor.b * ((tiles.x*tiles.y)-1.0);

    highp vec2 quad1;
    quad1.y = floor(floor(blueColor) / tiles.y);
    quad1.x = floor(blueColor) - (quad1.y * tiles.x);

    highp vec2 quad2;
    quad2.y = floor(ceil(blueColor) / tiles.y);
    quad2.x = ceil(blueColor) - (quad2.y * tiles.x);

    highp vec2 texPos1;
    texPos1.x = (quad1.x / tiles.x) + 0.5/colTexSize.x + (1.0/(tiles.x - colTexSize.x) * textureColor.r);
    texPos1.y = (quad1.y / tiles.y) + 0.5/colTexSize.y + (1.0/(tiles.y - colTexSize.y) * textureColor.g);

    highp vec2 texPos2;
    texPos2.x = (quad2.x / tiles.x) + 0.5/colTexSize.x + (1.0/(tiles.x - colTexSize.x) * textureColor.r);
    texPos2.y = (quad2.y / tiles.y) + 0.5/colTexSize.y + (1.0/(tiles.y - colTexSize.y) * textureColor.g);

    lowp vec4 newColor1 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos1);
    lowp vec4 newColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos2);

    lowp vec4 newColor = mix(newColor1, newColor2, fract(blueColor));
    gl_FragColor = mix(textureColor, vec4(newColor.rgb, textureColor.w), intensity);
}
```

Comment: why you don't change 63.0 ?. I change is 15.0?

Comment: why is it 63? 63 = 2 ^ 6 - 1?

Comment: yep. i try and 63 or 15 working. but have a effect different.

Comment: when i use 4x4. I choose 63 or 15?

Comment: Thank your for god answer. :)

Comment: I know. Because i try it and have error. But this solve of you is god.